# Vuetify data iterator string formatting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using v-data-iterator from [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-iterator/) and loading data from a crypto API into it. I have problem visualizing JS object keys as something different than 'price_date' for example. It should be displayed as "Price date" on the UI. How can I do that?

[image]

The data for the UI is taken from:

```
keys: [
        'Currency',
        'Price',
        'price_date',
        'num_of_exchanges',
        'market_cap',
        'market_cap_dominance',
        'High',
        'high_time_stamp',
      ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this codepen I made: https://codepen.io/cmfc31/pen/yLjLJZL?editors=1010

Instead of messing up the original keys in the array you could just create a object like this, to set whatever name you want:

```js
data () {
  return {
    ...
    keysName: {
      name: 'My name is',
      calories: "Calooories",
      fat: "FAT32",
      carbs: "Carbsss",
      protein: "AAA",
      sodium: "BBB",
      calcium: "CCC",
      iron: "DDD",
      
    },
    keys: [
      'name',
      'calories',
      'fat',
      'carbs',
      'protein',
      'sodium',
      'calcium',
      'iron',
    ],
    ...
  }
},
```

Then in your template simple get the value like this `keysName[key]`:

```html
<v-list dense>
  <v-list-item
    v-for="(key, index) in filteredKeys"
    :key="index"
  >
    <v-list-item-content :class="{ 'blue--text': sortBy === key }">
      {{ keysName[key] }}:
    </v-list-item-content>
    ...
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: Hi. Your solution works correctly. I've altered it a bit to suit my needs in this way:
keysRenamed: {
        currency: 'Currency',
        price: 'Price',
        'price date': 'Price date',
        'number of exchanges': 'Number of exchanges',
        'market cap': 'Market cap',
        'market cap dominance': 'Market cap dominance',
        high: 'High',
        'high time stamp': 'High time stamp',
      },
      

{{ keysRenamed[key] }}

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the keys as per the requirement by splitting it using [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and then join by using [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const keys = [
  'Currency',
  'Price',
  'price_date',
  'num_of_exchanges',
  'market_cap',
  'market_cap_dominance',
  'High',
  'high_time_stamp',
];

const updatedKeys = keys.map(item => {
  const splittedStr = item.split('_');
    splittedStr[0] = splittedStr[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splittedStr[0].slice(1);
  item = splittedStr.join(' ');
  return item;
});

console.log(updatedKeys);
```

Comment: This only works for vanilla JS and only displays correctly in the console. If you then say "this.keys = updatedKeys", it breaks the UI and you get:

Currency:
ZIL
Price: 0.035296579
Price date:
Num of exchanges:
Market cap:
Market cap dominance:
High: 0.23705707
High time stamp:

As you see, you don't get values against multiword strings.

Comment: Besides, this is the same as directly changing 'price_date' to 'Price date' in the keys array. It still breaks the UI. I believe I need a Vuetify solution.

Comment: Like `v-data-table` contains two properties for each column . One is key which is used to bind the values and another one is display property. So what I thought is that you can assign that modified keya to the display property.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to fix this Vuetify UI element by modifying the original array for the multi words:

```
this.crypto.push({
        name: el.name,
        currency: el.currency,
        price: el.price,
        'price date': el.price_date,
        'number of exchanges': el.num_exchanges,
        'market cap': el.market_cap,
        'market cap dominance': el.market_cap_dominance,
        high: el.high,
        'high time stamp': el.high_timestamp,
      });
```

and the keys array accordingly:

```
keys: [
    'currency',
    'price',
    'price date',
    'number of exchanges',
    'market cap',
    'market cap dominance',
    'high',
    'high time stamp',
  ],
```

[image]